# Strange Flash Compiler Errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors, flash-cs5

I am making a very simple slideshow.. I have made others with the same script with no errors.
This is a simple slideshow with 7 buttons at the bottom to jump to various points in the show.

I get the following errors if I type ANYTHING in my actions pane, written exactly as they are shown:

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions, Frame 1, Line 1 1023: Incompatible Override.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions, Frame 1, Line 1 1023: Incompatible Override.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions, Frame 1, Line 1 1021: Duplicate Function Definition.
MainTimeline, Line 1                     1000: Ambiguous Reference to frame1.

Regardless of what I put in the script it triggers those errors. Even if all I enter is a basic command and even if it is commented out as shown:
//stop;

Here is my script:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic1);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic2);
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic3);
button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic4);
button5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic5);
button6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic6);
button7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showpic7);

function showpic1(Event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay("picture1");
}

function showpic2(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("picture2");
}

function showpic3(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("picture3");
}

function showpic4(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("piturec4");
}

function showpic5(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("picture5");
}

function showpic6(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("picture6");
}

function showpic7(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay("picture7");
}
```

Comment: Ok.. It is mostly working now.. All I did was remove the first few frames of my actions layer.. I have no idea what caused this or why that fixed it though.. I went to the actions layer, inserted a keyframe at frame 10, and removed the actions from frames 1-9.. All buttons work until you are past the point where "picture6" is targeted.. then no buttons work..

Answer (score 0):

You should use lowercase "event" to name your variable in each of the listeners. "Event" is a class name, while "event" is an unused identifier which you can use as a variable.

```
function showpic1(event:MouseEvent):void{
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you have probably copied and pasted these functions elsewhere on the same timeline. Incompatible override happens when you have two functions with the same name, but different sets of arguments and return type. Most likely you've declared a function that uses the name of a built-in function. Duplicated function definition means that you have declared the same function twice, literally. Ambiguous reference is the result of the former: but this is so because your code was used in a template where the result of using it in the template have created an ambiguity. The functions with names `frame#` are generated by Flash CS for navigating between the frames.

Comment: Maybe I should have given more detail... The above is ALL of my script. It is just a basic slideshow with 7 buttons to hump from slide to slide. The funtions shown are the only ones I have. I did not rename anything to post that, everything you see is what I have.. There is no other script elsewhere on the timeline, there is no reference to frame numbers or other functions beyond what is shown.

Comment: I also tried the lowercase "event" but no difference... I think all of that is irrelevant also since If I delete ALL my script and just type one character in the actions pane it will give the exact same 4 errors.

Comment: I didnt copy anything.. Why is slide show suspicious? I have about 20 pictures, with tweens to transition from pic to pic. there are 7 buttons that should go to different points in the timeline.

Comment: I saved it in the beginning with just the images, no tweens, and the script written out. All buttons work. After I added the text and tweens and saved it as another name it started generating errors.

Comment: When I say "slideshow" I mean that I am building this project to act as a slideshow on a website. All the code is posted above. There is no other code involved.. Everything I have is posted in here. Right or wrong, moving it so the actions layer begins at frame 10 rather than frame 1 seems to have worked. I do not understand why, but it has. There is just one little glitch in there I am trying to figure out. The buttons ALL work until it reaches the frame representing "picture6".. anything past that point and NONE of the buttons work anymore..